# What are the fieldnames in AD for a user?

Tags: active-directory

Im trying to make a c# app that extracts users from AD. And with the AD im working on there are a lot if wierd names for the fields in a user object.

```
name = fullname
mail = email
telephoneNumber = phone number
```

(yeah, not much wierdness yet... but:)

```
sn = surname
co = country
l = city
st = state
```

So my question is there a list of the fieldnames that i can extract for a user or are they setup by the administrator (ifso i have to ask him for his crazy keywords)?

Comment: That is a good question...  And now you can vote!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AD is basically a customized-for-windows LDAP server. Is [this](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/LDAP_attributes_active_directory.htm) and [this](http://www.dovestones.com/products/Active_Directory_User_Import_Features.asp) the kind of information you're looking for?

There are extensions and alterations that can be made to it, such as for integrating Exchange or other services with AD, so you can't necessarily count on every AD environment being exactly the same. But the basic authentication fields shouldn't change.

You can google for information on importing/exporting bulk information in AD for information about fields and attributes. There are plenty of tools for moving data to and from text files and AD out there.

Comment: Ah, just what I wanted :-)

Comment: I have acceptet but i have too little street creed around here to up it, sry.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use ADExplorer (from SysInternals, now owned by Microsoft) and occasionally ADSIEdit for all of my AD property needs.  Really helpful when writing code...

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar information not long ago and found this resource quite usefull : [link text](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/LDAP_attributes_active_directory.htm#LDAP_Attribute_)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an ldap browser is the easiest way. Or lookup the active directory ldap schema

Answer (score 0):

We have a product Called Keck at techtoolbox.com  You may want to check it out. It may do what you are needing already.